I have issue with Memory limit exceeded
I have make a function that read & write PDF using pdf-lib.js, pdfjs-dist package. first my memory limit is 2GB and got error Memory limit exceeded, after I try to increase cloud memory to 4GB but still got the same error ( PDF file, file size 25 MB ). how to fix it?

